# no default constructor for JPA entity with Kotlin even with noarg plugin

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have read that you need the *kotlin-maven-noarg* compiler plugin for entity classes in order for it to generate default-parameter less cosntructor.

But the application does not start with the following error:

> No default constructor for entity

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    {...}
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>

                    <pluginOptions>
                        <option>jpa:annotation=javax.persistence.Entity</option>
                    </pluginOptions>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        {...}
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.1.0</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

        {...}

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = arrayOf(VedicaConfig::class))
class InitStructures {
    private var vedicaDBInit: VedicaDBInit? = null

    @Before
    fun init() {
        vedicaDBInit = VedicaDBInit()
    }

    @Test
    fun initClientFolders() {
    }
}
```

I'm using Intellij IDEA with Kotlin 1.1.0, so for deployment I just click debug/run with Tomcat run configuration selected and for running test I just right click on the test class and also click run/debug.

Comment: There is default constructor if you are using no-args plugin, but problem is that is could be accessed only through reflection, since it generated in compile time.

Comment: I think the `no-args` only works on classes marked with a subset of annotations, you should be able to configure your own annotations for the plugin.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried running your Maven `compile` goal before running your test? I've found that Intellij's default configurations for Kotlin run/test don't fire Maven plugins and therefore don't apply the no-arg plugin.

Try running your `compile` goal and then running your test again.

Comment: Is it possible to change the default behavior of IntelliJ to run unit tests via gradle? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Finally after a few attempts found how to fix it:

- Open Run/Debug Configurations window *(Run > Edit Configurations)*
- Select your existing Spring boot run configuration
- Add the following presets in Program arguments field:

  `-Xplugin=$KOTLIN_HOME/lib/noarg-compiler-plugin.jar -P plugin:org.jetbrains.kotlin.noarg:preset=jpa`
- Click ok to save configuration
- Stop and Run project again

[image: Run configuration screenshot]

Useful link: [No-arg compiler plugin info](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#jpa-support)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I was using gradle build btw.

What worked for me was, Instead of running default run config that intellij provides I created a new run config of type gradle

On the `Gradle project` selected my project and
on `Tasks` selected `bootRun`

And then ran my project and it worked for me

[image]

Comment: I think you could also select `classes` or `testClasses`.  This is what the micronaut framework suggests you do as part of setting to develop using it.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with intellij/gradle/kotlin.

In my case I always started the webapplication by calling the main method through intellij editor Run-Icon. I don't know what excatly is going wrong but somehow the build process wasn't finished correctly.

In contrast, If I started the webapplication from console by calling `./gradlew bootRun` everything worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

This was an Intellij bug and has been fixed in the following versions:

- IDEA 171.2455 + Kotlin plugin 1.1.0-dev-6111.
- IDEA 171.2272.14 (EAP) + Kotlin plugin 1.1.0-beta-17.

Details here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15686

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error until I noticed @LynAs's comment; then I remembered that there is a setting in IntelliJ that determines how to build and run your project. It is under `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Build and run using`. Pick `Gradle (Default)` because if you pick `IntelliJ IDEA` your builds might not run fine. There is a message above that line that says:

> In a pure Java/Kotlin project, building and running by means of the IDE might be faster, thanks to optimizations. **Note, that the IDE doesn't support all Gradle plugins and the project might not be built correctly with some of them.**

Therefore, it is preferable to use the Gradle build tool instead of IntelliJ's build tool.

[image]