# kotlin-jpa plugin not creating empty constructors for Junit tests

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, junit

I have a Spring Boot Kotlin project with a database. I have JUnit tests that use an embedded database.

Here is the `@Entity` I want to test

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
data class Client(
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        val id: UUID,

        @Column(name = "modified_on")
        var modifiedOn: OffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(),
)
```

When I run the test using gradle (`./gradlew clean test`) the tests succeed.

When I run the test through IntelliJ (right click > run all tests), I get an error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity
```

The [docs on the Kotlin website](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#jpa-support) make it clear - using the plugin 'kotlin-jpa' will automatically create no-arg constructors for classes annotated with `@Entity`

If I go to Project Structure > Facets > Kotlin > Kotlin main or test > Compiler Plugins, I can see two plugins: kotlin-allopen and kotlin-noarg. They appear to be configured correctly, and kotlin-noarg specifies `@Entity`.

I've specified the plugin in build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.41'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.3.41'
    // kotlin-jpa plugin allows no-arg constructors, e.g. on @Entity
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa' version '1.3.41'
}
```

How can I get JUnit tests that depend on the kotlin-noarg plugin to run in IntelliJ?

---

Related:

- [kotlin-jpa plugin not generating default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228910/kotlin-jpa-plugin-not-generating-default-constructor)
- [no default constructor for JPA entity with Kotlin even with noarg plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170391/no-default-constructor-for-jpa-entity-with-kotlin-even-with-noarg-plugin)

These don't have a resolution. They are also not specific to JUnit and IntelliJ - the plugin works otherwise.

- [Kotlin with JPA: default constructor hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038177/kotlin-with-jpa-default-constructor-hell)

The resolution here doesn't work.

Comment: Opened an issue for this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-223663

Answer (score 1):

My issue with this was trying to use Kotlin's new IR backend:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions { 
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
            useIR = true
        }
    }
```

Removing `useIR = true` solved the plugin issue